# "from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file": what defines the beginning of the file?

Tags: python, comments

The Python  script

```
'''
a
'''

from __future__ import print_function
```

works well (i.e., does nothing), but

```
'''
a
'''

'''
b
'''
from __future__ import print_function
```

causes:

```
File "C:\test.py", line 8
    from __future__ import print_function
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

Why?

---

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future says that:

> A future statement must appear near the top of the module. The only
>   lines that can appear before a future statement are:
>
> - the module docstring (if any),
> - **comments**,
> - **blank lines**, and
> - other future statements.

The second example only contains comments and blank lines before the `from __future__ import print_function`, and yet it doesn't work.

I use Python 2.7.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> ... which seems to be in contradiction with the second example I gave.

No, because those are not comments, they are strings.

The first string is elided from the code as a docstring, but the second string becomes a statement in the code consisting of the string itself. `__future__` imports *must* be before *all* code-relevant lines, even those that have no effect.

Comment: Interesting.. Thanks